# Tilted metallic plate touching two capacitor plates

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

> A parallel plate capacitor of capacitance $C$ is as shown. A thin metal plate A is placed between the plates of the given capacitor in such a way that its edges touch the two plates as shown. Find the capacitance across $P$ and $Q$.
>
> [image]

I think the answer is $0$ as the current literally passes through the capacitor since metal is touching both the plates.

But the answer given is infinity, "because $d$ becomes zero". What does this mean? Why is my answer wrong?

Comment: I think I saw this question in PSE before but I can't find it ...

Comment: its really bugging me

Comment: Infinite capacitance in parallel with a short is a short.

Comment: [This post](https://qr.ae/pGKos0) might be useful.